# Regular Expression for (1ab09cs001)

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to separate string i.e combination of Subject Name with Subject Code into two parts in java.
The originalString can be **ANYTHING** like "ABC (01dfv)" , "BCD (sdfsd) etc...
The subject code always written in () and subject name will always prefix the bracket.
**Example** :

```
String originalString = "Computer Science (06cs43)"
String subjectName="Computer Science"
String subjectCode="06cs43"
```

I am using string.replaceAll but not able to find out the **regular** expression for extracting or replacing the subject code.

The size of the subject code is not fixed.

Comment: Why do you need regex if the string is always `"Computer Science (06cs43)"`? Or is it no? Then please describe the format of the names and codes, to make a usable regex from it.

Comment: Why not simply split on WS, no need for a regexp here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use regex here. You can just do this

```
String orS="Computer Science (06cs43)";
String subjectName=orS.subString(0,orS.indexOf('(')-1);
String subjectCode=orS.subString(orS.indexOf('('),orS.length()-2)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me.
It was my first question on stackoverflow and thanx @usama8800 correcting the logic and making is easier.

Answer (score 2):

Just try with followinf regex:

```
"^([^(]+) \\(([^)]+)\\)$"
```

Or better:

```
String originalString = "Computer Science (06cs43)";

String[] parts = originalString.split("\\(");

String subjectName = parts[0].trim();
String subjectCode = null;
if (parts.length > 1) {
    subjectCode = parts[1].replaceAll("\\)$", "");
}
```